# Getter returning null in different class

Tags: java, android, firebase

while making an Android app, I have ran in the following problem:

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
...
private String token;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
tokenSetter();
}
private void tokenSetter() {
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w("TRAZENITOKEN", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getToken();
                setToken(token);

                Log.d("TRAZENITOKEN", "onGetToken: " + token);

                // Log and toast
                // Log.d("TRAZENITOKEN", "onComplete: " + token);
            });
}
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

I know that the token value is being set as in an another method inside this MainActivity class, when I call getToken(), I get the value.

However, when I try to call getToken from an another Activity, something like this:

```
...
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        FirebaseActions firebaseActions = new FirebaseActions();
        MainActivity  mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        //firebaseActions.setUserNameOnToken(editText.getText().toString());
        if(mainActivity.getToken() != null) editText.setText(mainActivity.getToken());
        else editText.setText("Skafiskafnjak");
    });
```

(I opted for the editText.setText method for debugging purposes, I am going to use it in the commented way)
The code snippet above always goes to the else part as the getToken is null.
Why does it return null in this class, if it returns a value in it's own class?
Could it be perhaps because I did
            MainActivity  mainActivity = new MainActivity();

An answer would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MainActivity  mainActivity = new MainActivity();

This activity instance is not the same one that the Android system created where you see the token being set. Besides, **we never create an activity with `new`.** The Android system creates activities according to the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and your code must work within this structure. To pass data between activities, you need to send it in the `Intent` when you call `startActivity()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: What if the activity that the data belongs to isn't directly linked to the target activity?

For example, if the current class is 5 activities away from the one where the data is stored, should I Intent my way trough all of them or is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Or better yet, what if I have a FirebaseActions class which is consisted of methods and I need to access something from MainActivity which is an Activity and a method from FirebaseActions class is called from a different activity? Sure, I could pass data as a function parameter but since that activity doesn't have the data (without intents trough potentially multiple activities), it would be preferable if the FirebaseActions class could access that data directly.

Comment: Yes, one solution is to pass data through all of the Activities with Intents. Alternatively, you could redesign your app to use a single Activity and Fragments for the different screens. This will allow you to keep data in the host Activity and pass it to each Fragment when you swap them. I'm not sure what `FirebaseActions` is. If this is a custom class, you can probably implement `Parcelable` in order to pass it in an Intent. Check the docs for how to do this. I'm not familiar with Firebase, but my inclination is that you can use `LiveData` to manage some of what you are doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new activity causes new instance of that activity, therefor a new token which would be null

Send the token through the intent as String data from your MainActivity, and then from the second Activity, grab that String data(token), and do with it whatever you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("token", yourTokenValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in onCreate method of your SecondActivity,you can use getIntent().getStringExtra("token"); to retrieve the token value which was passed from the first Activity

```
String token= getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
```